# Keysight oscilloscope outputs an .scp file

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm an electronics engineering student that used an oscilloscope for very first time.

I tried to capture an screenshot from oscilloscope to my usb flash drive, but I forgot to change the file format to an graphical image format like .jpg .png, instead of that; the file is in .scp format.

Is there any way to visualize this file? (I'm assuming that the .scp file is similar to .svg)

I'm sending the some portion  (because of the maximum character restriction) of the content of the .scp file as a code block below:

```
<setup prod="InfiniiVision" ver="02.65.2021030741" srver="2.0">
<command_section/>
<control_section>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>expandMode</name>
<val>0,"ground"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>wfmAntialiasing</name>
<val>1,"on"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>storeDemoState</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>screenSaverSelect</name>
<val>1,"logo"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>screenSaverTimeout</name>
<val>180</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>screenSaverText</name>
<val>KEYSIGHT TECHNOLOGIES</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>delayedMainView</name>
<val>0,"zoomWin"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>autoscaleMode</name>
<val>2,"custom"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>autoscaleFastDebugMode</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>autoscaleChan</name>
<val>1,"all"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>autoscaleTrig</name>
<val>1,"edge"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>autoscaleTime</name>
<val>1,"auto"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>autoscaleAcq</name>
<val>1,"normal"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>digActivityLoc</name>
<val>0,"docked"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>fiftyOhmImpedLock</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>lanLedDisplayMode</name>
<val>0,"lan"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>displayMeasStats</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>transparentReadout</name>
<val>1,"on"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>remoteLang</name>
<val>0,"InfiniiVision"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>quickActionMode</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>muxKnobMode</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>deepAnalysisMode</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>userIdnString</name>
<val>AGILENT TECHNOLOGIES,DSO-X 2004A,MY54490461,02.65.2021030741</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>timeMode</name>
<val>2,"xy"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>zoomMode</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>segmentedState</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>runMode</name>
<val>1,"run"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>timeRef</name>
<val>1,"center"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>mainScale</name>
<val>4563361313833405645</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>mainDelay</name>
<val>0</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>dlydScale</name>
<val>4512825593480736141</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>dlydDelay</name>
<val>0</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>timeVernier</name>
<val>1,"on"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>wfmMemLockTime</name>
<val>1,"on"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>trigMode</name>
<val>1,"edge"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>trigCoup</name>
<val>2,"ac"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>trigHfRej</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>trigNRej</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>trigHoldoff</name>
<val>4496133457586457658</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>trigSweepMode</name>
<val>1,"auto"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>edgeSrc</name>
<val>7,"wgen"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>edgeSlope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>glitchSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>glitchPolarity</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>glitchMode</name>
<val>1,"lt"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>glitchMinWidth</name>
<val>4491629857959087162</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>glitchMaxWidth</name>
<val>4494622300311939371</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>glitchRangeMinWidth</name>
<val>4491629857959087162</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>glitchRangeMaxWidth</name>
<val>4494622300311939372</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>tvSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>tvStd</name>
<val>0,"ntsc"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>tvPolarity</name>
<val>0,"negative"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>tvMode</name>
<val>0,"field1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>tvLine</name>
<val>1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>tvGenTime</name>
<val>4538295070669382149</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>tvGenEdge</name>
<val>1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>tvHorzSyncEnable</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>tvHorzSync</name>
<val>0</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>trigHoldoffTvField</name>
<val>0</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>patnPattern</name>
<val>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>patnQual</name>
<val>0,"entered"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>patnChan</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>seqPattern1</name>
<val>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>seqPattern2</name>
<val>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqE1Src</name>
<val>-1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqE1Slope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqE2Src</name>
<val>-1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqE2Slope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqFind</name>
<val>0,"p1Enter"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqTrigger</name>
<val>0,"p2Enter"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>seqReset</name>
<val>0,"none"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>seqEventCount</name>
<val>1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>seqTimeout</name>
<val>4502148214488346440</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>nthEdgeSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>nthEdgeSlope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>nthEdgeIdleTime</name>
<val>4512825593480736141</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>nthEdgeEdgeNum</name>
<val>1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>trigLevelSel</name>
<val>0,"norm"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>edgeTransSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>edgeTransSlope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>edgeTransQual</name>
<val>2,"gt"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>edgeTransQualTime</name>
<val>4491629857959087162</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>runtSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>runtPolarity</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>runtQual</name>
<val>0,"none"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>runtQualTime</name>
<val>4491629857959087162</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>setupHoldClkSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>setupHoldDataSrc</name>
<val>1,"ch2"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>setupHoldClkSlope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>setupHoldSetupTime</name>
<val>4476910133257361045</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>setupHoldHoldTime</name>
<val>4476910133257361045</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>usbBitRate</name>
<val>12,"b12M"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>usbTrig</name>
<val>0,"sop"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>usbDpSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>usbDnSrc</name>
<val>1,"ch2"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>orData</name>
<val>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>delayArmSrc</name>
<val>0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>delayArmSlope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>delayTrigSrc</name>
<val>1,"ch2"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>delayTrigSlope</name>
<val>1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>delayTime</name>
<val>4481413732884731541</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>delayEvents</name>
<val>1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>serialBusSel</name>
<val>0,"serial1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>serialBusMuxIndex</name>
<val>0,"serial1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>serialDecodeMode</name>
<val muxpos="0">1,"i2c"</val>
<val muxpos="1">1,"i2c"</val>
<val muxpos="2">1,"i2c"</val>
<val muxpos="3">1,"i2c"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>serialDecodeState</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"off"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"off"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"off"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>serialDecodeMasterState</name>
<val>0,"off"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>i2cClkSrc</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"ch1"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"ch1"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"ch1"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>i2cDataSrc</name>
<val muxpos="0">1,"ch2"</val>
<val muxpos="1">1,"ch2"</val>
<val muxpos="2">1,"ch2"</val>
<val muxpos="3">1,"ch2"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>i2cTrig</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"start"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"start"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"start"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"start"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>i2cAddr</name>
<val muxpos="0">-1</val>
<val muxpos="1">-1</val>
<val muxpos="2">-1</val>
<val muxpos="3">-1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>i2cDataQual</name>
<val muxpos="0">2,"equal"</val>
<val muxpos="1">2,"equal"</val>
<val muxpos="2">2,"equal"</val>
<val muxpos="3">2,"equal"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>i2cData</name>
<val muxpos="0">-1</val>
<val muxpos="1">-1</val>
<val muxpos="2">-1</val>
<val muxpos="3">-1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>i2cData2</name>
<val muxpos="0">-1</val>
<val muxpos="1">-1</val>
<val muxpos="2">-1</val>
<val muxpos="3">-1</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>i2cDecodeAddrMode</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"addr7Bit"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"addr7Bit"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"addr7Bit"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"addr7Bit"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiTrigger</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"mosi"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"mosi"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"mosi"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"mosi"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiClkSrc</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"ch1"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"ch1"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"ch1"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"ch1"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiMosiSrc</name>
<val muxpos="0">1,"ch2"</val>
<val muxpos="1">1,"ch2"</val>
<val muxpos="2">1,"ch2"</val>
<val muxpos="3">1,"ch2"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiMisoSrc</name>
<val muxpos="0">2,"ch3"</val>
<val muxpos="1">2,"ch3"</val>
<val muxpos="2">2,"ch3"</val>
<val muxpos="3">2,"ch3"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiFrame</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"notCs"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"notCs"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"notCs"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"notCs"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiFrameSrc</name>
<val muxpos="0">3,"ch4"</val>
<val muxpos="1">3,"ch4"</val>
<val muxpos="2">3,"ch4"</val>
<val muxpos="3">3,"ch4"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiClkPolarity</name>
<val muxpos="0">1,"positive"</val>
<val muxpos="1">1,"positive"</val>
<val muxpos="2">1,"positive"</val>
<val muxpos="3">1,"positive"</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>spiMosiDataLength</name>
<val muxpos="0">8</val>
<val muxpos="1">8</val>
<val muxpos="2">8</val>
<val muxpos="3">8</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>spiData</name>
<val muxpos="0">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
<val muxpos="1">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
<val muxpos="2">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
<val muxpos="3">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="i32">
<name>spiMisoDataLength</name>
<val muxpos="0">8</val>
<val muxpos="1">8</val>
<val muxpos="2">8</val>
<val muxpos="3">8</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="str">
<name>spiMisoData</name>
<val muxpos="0">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
<val muxpos="1">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
<val muxpos="2">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
<val muxpos="3">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="f64">
<name>spiTimeout</name>
<val muxpos="0">4532020583610935537</val>
<val muxpos="1">4532020583610935537</val>
<val muxpos="2">4532020583610935537</val>
<val muxpos="3">4532020583610935537</val>
</ctrl>
<ctrl type="enum">
<name>spiBitOrder</name>
<val muxpos="0">0,"msb"</val>
<val muxpos="1">0,"msb"</val>
<val muxpos="2">0,"msb"</val>
<val muxpos="3">0,"msb"</val>
</ctrl>
```

Comment: This looks like the settings for your oscilloscope, not the waveform itself. Maybe the waveform *is* listed further down

Comment: Secure copy protocol is just the wrong file. You saved the settings not the waveform

Answer (score 5):

The SCP file does not contain any captured data, it only contains current settings used to capture and view the data such as trigger and cursors

Answer (score 3):

Many such scopes will have saved a ‘trace’ .tif data simultaneously with the .scp setup data. You can open tiff image data with a graphics program.

Refer to the oscilloscope manual for your particular model.